# On google scripts, is there a way to show a message or prompt to a single user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a working script on Spreadsheet that pops up prompts and alerts on editing certain ranges, but when multiple users are on the sheet at the same time this pops up to every single one regardless of whom made the change.

Is there a way every message appears only to the user who edited or even triggered it?

And if not, a way to find out how many users have the sheet open so to disable this when more than one?

The trigger is on an admin (owner) account and the sheet is protected, so only certain cells are editable by normal users, and the script completes this cells. Just to mention having triggers on user accounts wouldn't work as the don't have permission to edit everything or it d' defeat the purpose.

Comment: Could you maybe share a sample of the behavior you are seeing. A piece of reproducible code? or a copy of the sheet? Is hard to know if something is wrong from what you just have told.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick

```
function onEdit(e){
  
  var userMakingTheEdit = e.user;
  var UserLoggedON = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
  if (userMakingTheEdit == UserLoggedON)
  {
    // Show alert
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake.

There was a bug on loop which made that behavior that i had trouble finding, now it's fixed and it works as it should.

Using onEdit(e) works correctly only running the code with prompts and alerts on that single users.

Thank you either way on responding, the last one was actually really helpful on something else, i appreciate it.